# Jquery html() issue with multiple cases

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I know this is not right and i cant seem to get it to work:

```
 $(".green").html(function() {
        if (n == 0) { "<span>0</span>" };
        if (n == 1) { "<span>2</span>" };
        if (n > 1) { "<span>3</span>"};

    });
```

I basically want change the html of an element to 3 different things if n's value is 0, 1 or greater then 1.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you also need to return the info `return "<span>0</span>";`

modified code

```
var n = 1;
$(".green").html(function() {
    if (n == 0) { return "<span>0</span>"; }
    if (n == 1) { return "<span>2</span>"; }
    if (n > 1) { return "<span>3</span>"; }

});
```

Comment: @estern: Don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem.